# Struggling to figure out how to write a certain function

Tags: c, function

I've been trying for quite a while now to write a function in my C program which will perform a task if a given array does not contain a certain letter, otherwise if the array does contain this letter, another function is called and the program continues on elsewhere.

Here is an example of one such function I attempted:

```
int Asterisk(){
    int v;

    for(v=0; v<sizeof Mask; v++){
        if(Mask[v] != '*'){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this function returns 1 when

```
Mask[0] != '*'
```

I can't figure out how to check every element of the array before returning a value, rather than just checking the first element.

Any help/guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What does **the function is broken**??? mean?

Comment: Could you show what have you done so far?  What is contained in array?  Is it an array of `char`s?

Comment: By "the function is broken" do you mean that it `return`s ?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure how to phrase that. I will edit my OP so that it is more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
int Asterisk()
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < sizeof Mask && Mask[i] != '*' ) ++i;

    return i == sizeof Mask;
}
```

Though as for me I would write the function such a way that if an asterisk is present in the array then the function returns 1.

```
int Asterisk()
{
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < sizeof Mask && Mask[i] != '*' ) ++i;

    return i != sizeof Mask;
}
```

and in the caller use it like

if ( !Asterisk() ) { /* do something */ }

That is if an asterisk is present in the array then the function returns 1 otherwise returns 0.

If the character array contains strings then you could simply use standard C function `strchr` declared in header `<string.h>`

Answer (score 1):

By array, you mean a simple string ? If it that case, you just need to write a function taking a string and the letter to find and return 0 if the string doesn't contain this letter else 1 at the first occurrence of the letter.

Comment: I have tried to do this but there is a problem I can't solve. I'll add this to my OP now.

Answer (score 0):

```
int Asterisk()
{
    int v;

    bool exists = false;
    for(v=0; v<sizeof Mask; v++){
         if(Mask[v] != '*'){
             exists = true;
              break;
         }
    }
return exists;
}
```